# Reinstall windows on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

So let me start off by saying that I'm a complete beginner at Linux in general. I wanted to install Ubuntu along Windows 10 to learn slowly. I did this by booting off of a flash drive, but I made the mistake of thinking when it said it would replace everything, that it meant *just on the flashdrive*. So after managing to remove my entire OS (thankfully there was nothing important on my hard drive), I need windows back so I can *sucessfully* install Ubuntu on the side.

Now I have a windows 10 iso on a flash drive, and when I go to install it apparently, I somehow have a FAT32 hard disk now, which in result I get a prompt stating that I can't install windows to fat32.

I can't seem to find many articles on what to do because I'm unsure whether I have to completely wipe my HDD or if there's an easy solution to this. Any guidance someone can help me out with will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to wipe for dual boot, the same principles are applicable regardless of what OS is previously installed. That said, it's much easier to install Windows first and if you do that then you can leave unallocated space to install Ubuntu alongside later and avoid the hassle of shrinking partitions.

Comment: @CelticWarrior Which brings me back to the main issue. I can't install windows because of this error I'm getting.

Comment: TBH, not an error but more of that later. First of all, installing Windows is off-topic here so you shouldn't expect help with it specifically. Before installing an OS, any OS, you need to be familiar with partitions, file systems and the given OS requirements and how to deal with a bare-metal installation and also when there's something in the target drive already. I'm talking about removing all the partitions already in the target drive and creating new ones. That can be done with the Windows installer. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) As explained already I won't delve into Windows installation. The dual boot is on topic and for that there are many other things you need to be familiar with. Any factory installed Windows 8/8.1/10 is in UEFI mode so you need to also know this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI